# What is the minimum separation between two A380's while taxing in-line?

Tags: airport, taxiing, airport-design

If you are tailing another A380 on the taxiway, how much separation do you need from your nose to the A380 that you are tailing?

Comment: I suggest asking a question like, "are there any regulations controlling the distance between aircraft while taxiing?" It would get a clear answer and would probably be more useful to the community than a question specific to one type of aircraft.